# Old show about a cave with magic stones?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember it had a child or children.

Probably about a family in a cave with magical stones.  Believe they were stones not crystals but they were colored.  The show was less animated and more realistic looking.

Comment: Gemstone cave?I think they used to fight monsters or enemies?Not so sure it was a long time ago I stumbled upon it.It still faintly in my mind today.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When would this have been?  You say "less animated," but you still mean it was animated, correct?

Comment: Note that you can always [edit] the question to include additional details; it's better than putting them in comments, that are less visible and searchable.

Answer (score 12):

[*Land of the Lost*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_the_Lost_(1974_TV_series)) (1974) fits in that it is now old, involved "caves" (the pylons) with gemstones which could be used to fight off enemies (the Sleestaks, dinosaurs) and it was partially animated in that there was much use of stop-motion filming.

[image]

Comment: The OP mentioned children- and *Land of the Lost* featured two human children (Will and Holly) and a pre-human child, Chaka

Comment: https://youtu.be/Hk-U6VXxki8 for example

Comment: @ Ifurini; Thanks for the edit.  Those who can, do, those who cannot depend on the good efforts of people like yourself.